# TeamCity Build Triggering - exclude changes in a specific directory

Tags: teamcity

Our build process generates a couple of files (with extension .file for sake of argument) that are automatically checked into git at the end of the process. This checkin triggers a new build so we have an infinite loop of builds triggering each other.

I have tried to solve this by using the following exclusion based build trigger options but neither seems to work:

```
-:**.file

-:comment=^automated checkin$:**
```

Is there something obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 5):

We have a simple rule to prevent .sql files checked into SVN from triggering a build with the following rule in the VCS Trigger Rules textbox:

```
-:**.sql
```

Maybe make sure the checkins only have files with the .file extension and no other file types.